# Counting li elements --> Then applying CSS = Loading Problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working with a CMS. In order to  show some list content I need a count on the list items to spread them evenly over the page. I did this function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() { 

    var count = $("#page_menu ul li").length;
    var breit = 945 / count;
    $("#page_menu li").css("width", breit);   
})
})
```

```css
      #page_menu ul {
       margin: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       }

#page_menu li {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     }


   #page_menu ul li {
     height: 50px;
     float: left;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 13px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_menu">

<ul class="nav menu mod-list">
  <li class="item-121"><a href="/index.php/about/feintaeschner" >Feintäschner</a></li><li class="item-122"><a href="/index.php/about/querfloete" >Querflöte</a></li><li class="item-123"><a href="/index.php/about/illustrator" >Illustrator</a></li><li class="item-124"><a href="/index.php/about/autor" >Autor</a></li></ul>

</div>

<button>change</button>
```

This does exactly what it is supposed to do - TOO LATE!

To be precise: The page loads and builds the list. The javascript afterwards performs its counting function and releases it to the CSS. However, by then the CSS relating to the list doesn't get the  information anymore. The button stays blank and without function regardless if it was placed before the javascript section or after. And it stays that way until I go a level down in the submenu with the same menu. Then it works fine.

And the other thing is, that I would like to load it by itself and not via clicking a button. How can I achieve this?

Sorry, I haven't been working this kind of stuff for the past 10 yrs. I am completely somewhat lost.

Comment: To make your width count on page load, you just need to put the code in `$(document).ready`. And the main question is still not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved. Didn't see the forest because it was full of trees. ;)